# SignalR cannot connect to Azure Redis on SSL

Tags: redis, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr-backplane, azure-redis-cache

I am currently hosting my redis cache server on Azure, and have signalR relying on it as the backbone using the following...

GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseRedis("Server",port,"password","eventKey");

This works find on port 6379 (non-SSL) but my chat app breaks when I try to connect to the SSL port (6380) of my Azure Redis server, and the hub is never started.  What could be the cause of this issue? Or am I doing something wrong?

This is the error that appears on /signalr/connect in my browser
net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can try this:

`GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseRedis(new RedisScaleoutConfiguration(connectionString, "YourServer"));`

And connection string something like:

connectionString="yourNameHere.cache.windows.net,ssl=true,password=YourPasswordKey"

Make sure you are using SignalR built with StackExchange.Redis (latest is gratest ;)

Comment: Nice! I actually did actually get it to work that day using the same exact method you have outlined above.  Upgraded all SignalR packages, and was able to use a connection string directly! The following post led me to that solution: https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/3383

Comment: you might want to add a port number to your connection string. e.g. "yourServerNameHere.cache.windows.net:yourPortNumberHere,ssl=true,password=YourPasswordKey"

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded the signalr core library to version 2.2.3.0 and used the below syntax, works like a charm.

```
var redisServer = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Constants.RedisServer].ToString();

var redisServerPassword = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[Constants.RedisServerPassword].ToString();

var connectionString = $"{redisServer},password={redisServerPassword},ssl=True,abortConnect=False";
GlobalHost.DependencyResolver.UseRedis(new RedisScaleoutConfiguration(connectionString, "APIIdentifierString"));
```

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else hits the issue, it seems that the default connection string provided by the Azure portal contains abortConnect=False.
Once I've removed that part, things started working for me.

Comment: FYI we use abortConnect=False in connection string and it works.